# Using HttpContextAccessor inside of injected class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Using ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview 5, I'm trying to access `HttpContextAccessor` from inside an `AppState` class that I'm injecting into my application.

Unfortunately I keep getting a `System.AggregateException` with a message of

> ''Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: [MyNameSpace].AppState
>   Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: [MyNameSpace].AppState':
>   Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor' while attempting to
>   activate '[MyNameSpace].AppState'.)'

My *Startup.cs* file is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<AppState>();

    // More services
}
```

and my *AppState.cs* file is as follows:

```
private HttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public AppState(HttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

I've checked online and it seems that just adding the `AddHttpContextAccessor` and `AddSingleton<T>` to my `ConfigureServices` method should do the trick but for some reason it isn't working.

As I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core and Dependency Injection, I just wanted to see if someone who knows what they are doing has any idea what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: What context do you expect to use in a singleton? The first that ever called your app?

Comment: It seems that you're using Blazor which is not based on HTTP requests so using `IHttpContextAccessor ` in your application's state doesn't really make sense and probably doesn't work.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is 'mix' server side Blazor with IdentityServer4. When IdentityServer4 completes the login it add values to the HttpContext.User property which I am then using as part of my AppState class. For the record however, DavidG's answer below does seem to have worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The `AddHttpContextAccessor()` method registers the service as a `IHttpContextAccessor` (note the `I` prefix to denote it is an interface) and that is what your class needs to explicitly accept in it's constructor:

```
private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public AppState(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

However, you should not be using this from a singleton class. HTTP requests are, unsurprisingly different per request.

Comment: `IHttpContextAccessor` is a singleton service and uses `AsyncLocal` to keep track of the "current" HTTP context instance thus it can be used in a singleton service as long as it's accessed within the scope of an HTTP request. Though it seems that OP is using Blazor which is not based on HTTP requests so using `IHttpContextAccessor ` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Although there seems to be some suggestion that what I'm trying to do is wrong, adding the 'I' has solved my problem (I knew the answer would be something silly!).